# Wordpress Tag Cloud Plugin That Allows For Custom Links

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to tie a tag cloud to content controlled by the isotope tiling system
(http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/introduction.html). When the user clicks a tag,it will filter the isotope content area to display only that tag (All in javascript, no postback)

In order for it to work I need to be able to replace the default behavior of the links in the tag  to:

```
<a href="#" data-filter=".metal">metal</a>
```

where metal is the tag/category

Is there any plugin that can currently do this or a painless way to edit the core tag cloud to do it.

Thanks!

Michael

Comment: did you ever get this to work? I got this to work in a similar way, (downloading an isotope plugin, then editing the CTC tag cloud widget and editing its output) but it only sorts what is loaded (first 10 posts), otherwise if the post hasn't already loaded it will sort to a blank when you click a tag that isn't present on the page load. I'd love to know how this has been working for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to change one of the base files but the "easiest" way to accomplish what you want would be editing where the tag cloud comes from.

File: sitename.com/wp-includes/category-template.php

Edit: Line 674-676

```
$a[] = "<a href='$tag_link' class='tag-link-$tag_id' title='" . esc_attr( call_user_func( $topic_count_text_callback, $real_count ) ) . "' style='font-size: " .
        str_replace( ',', '.', ( $smallest + ( ( $count - $min_count ) * $font_step ) ) )
        . "$unit;'>$tag_name</a>";
```

With

```
$a[] = "<a href='#' class='tag-link-$tag_id' title='" . esc_attr( call_user_func( $topic_count_text_callback, $real_count ) ) . "' style='font-size: " .
        str_replace( ',', '.', ( $smallest + ( ( $count - $min_count ) * $font_step ) ) )
        . "$unit;' data-filter='.$tag_name'>$tag_name</a>";
```

But personally this will change the link for anything that uses the tags.  So personally I would grab any tag cloud plugin that is out there and edit the output of the link on that instead.

Example:

Plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/configurable-tag-cloud-widget/

File: sitename.com/plugins/configurable-tag-cloud-widget/base.php

Edit: Line 281-283

```
$a[] = "<a href=\"$tag_link\" class=\"ctc-tag tag-link-$tag_id\" title=\"".attribute_escape(sprintf(__('%d topics'), $count))."\"$rel style=\"font-size: ".$tag_weight
            ."$unit;".(isset($tag_color) ? " color: $tag_color;" : "")
            ."\">$tag"."</a>".('yes' == $showcount ? " $postcount" : "");
```

With

```
$a[] = "<a href='#' data-filter='.$tag' class=\"ctc-tag tag-link-$tag_id\" title=\"".attribute_escape(sprintf(__('%d topics'), $count))."\"$rel style=\"font-size: ".$tag_weight
            ."$unit;".(isset($tag_color) ? " color: $tag_color;" : "")
            ."\">$tag"."</a>".('yes' == $showcount ? " $postcount" : "");
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, that was a perfect answer.